# How to create a themeable website?

Tags: css, html, themes, less

I am developing a website and i want to allow the user to switch themes (mainly colors,fonts etc, not layout).

My idea is to have a class on the body, say theme1, and then put all styling under that class:

```
.theme1{
    //less code here
}


.theme2{
    //less code here
}
```

That way, in order to switch theme, all I have to do is replace the class on the body.

Is that a good solution, is there a better way?

Comment: Seems to me that doing it that way would make the stylesheet unnecessarily more complex.  Why not just have multiple stylesheets, one for each theme, and switch between them using jquery/javascript?

Comment: @javram - I didn't mean that i'll put it all in one stylesheet, every theme will have it's own, and that way, it'll be clear what theme is currently applied, since all styles will be prefixed with theme1,theme2 etc.

Comment: @ftom2 but why prefix it?  Just use an alternate stylesheet switcher as javram suggested.  This one has been around forever:  http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/

Comment: @cimmanon - That article just proves my point, instead of that complex mechanism, all i have to do is just replace a class on the body tag.

Comment: The "complex mechanism" is so that the selected theme persists across page views, something you'll have to do with class replacement as well.  Alternate Style Sheets are supported in most User Agents these days, should JS fail.  There's no up side to your solution.

Comment: @cimmanon - Sorry, my bad, i forgot to mention this is a SPA (Single Page Application), so there is only one 'body' element and thus i only need to replace it in one place.

Comment: One thing to consider, especially if this is a public facing website is the best practices for using efficient css selectors,  not sure how concerned you are about fast loading,  but it can definitely slow things down if your css rules get too complex https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

Comment: @javram - it is not a public website, but nevertheless performance is an important issue, and i'm well aware of the 'be less specific' rule. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using LESS then it's pretty straightforward to wrap all your styling in a

```
body.theme-class { }
```

selector.

This seems reasonable; it makes changing the theme a simple case of changing the class on the body tag.